# Superimposing plots

Tags: plotting

I have a very basic question. Suppose I have two similar looking plots. May be they differ by some over all scaling (e.g, `f[x_]:= x^2-x^3` and `g[x_]:= 37(x^2-x^3)`). But I do not know their functional forms. Is there a way in mathematica to superimpose them to decide whether they are same up to a scaling?

Comment: `g[x]/f[x]`? Or using [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html).

Comment: Oh, so by "plots" you meant "functions"? `f[x_]` is not a plot, it is a function. A plot is a picture that depicts the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2 - x^3
g[x_] := 5 (x^2 - x^3)

Plot[{f[x], g[x], g[x]/f[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
g[x_] := 5 x (x^2 - x^3)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use this method if I have a numerical plot?

Comment: What do you mean with numerical plot? `ListPlot` ?

Comment: I have a plot which I got solving a differential equation using `ParametricNDSolveValue` . I want to compare it with another known  function.

Comment: Yes, for example `pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[t] + a f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f[10], {t, 0, 10}, {a}]` and then `Plot[pfun[a]/Sin[a], {a, 0, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks! So, all one has to check is to see whether `f[x]/g[x]` is a straight line. That line may not intersect the origin in general. If one gets almost straight line then the curves are very nearly equal. Are these statements correct?

Comment: Correct--------------------------------------